# How to get Tortoise HG to detect changes in files based on directory again

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

The simplest way I can describe this is that I have a project in Windows 7 under version control with tortoise HG version 2.8.1
using Mercurial-2.6.2, I am using bitbucket.org as my remote repository. When I go to click HG commit on a folder with a red exclamation point on it (meaning files that need to be committed).  It tells me

> No files found for this operation

But when I click on files in that directory that have the red exclamation point, It brings up the normal commit menu expecting me to write the normal commit message.

**So basically the problem is that it doesn't detect any files need comitting from the directory level when I click commit, despite there being a red exclamation point on the directory**.  Maybe this was caused by some other issues. I am sure it has to do with branches or heads, but I really don't understand that stuff as well as I would prefer.

I am willing to grab any info or screenshots from Tortoise HG or Bitbucket to help with the issue, just be sure to explain how to get that info. Here are some screenshots of the issue.

[image: Base Directory]

Here is inside the directory.

[image: Inside the directory]

Comment: What version of TortoiseHg and Mercurial do you use?

Comment: I use Tortoise HG 2.8.1
with Mercurial-2.6.2

Answer (score 2):

Repository on network share is **Bad Idea (tm)**

Move repository to local drive

Comment: This is a personal project. I appreciate the advice. But I really need to figure out an answer.

Comment: Did you try copying it to a local disk? Parts of mercurial behaves oddly in some cases around network shares. I wouldn't be surprised if this *is* the answer.