# Tortoisehg on a remote folder (ssh/sftp)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My hg repository is on a server that I can reach with ssh and sftp.
So I can mount the remote dir on my desktop (debian) and can edit the file there.

Now I would like to use Tortoisehg, but I would rather not to clone the repo locally, but just using the remote one that is now mounted locally.
How can I do th?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490261/how-to-get-tortoise-hg-to-detect-changes-in-files-based-on-directory-again. It's windows, but pattern is common

Answer (score 1):

> Now I would like to use Tortoisehg, but I would rather not to clone the repo locally, but just using the remote

It's, in common, The Bad Idea (tm) to use repository from network drive, but:

use this repo the same way, as you edited files in working dir of repository
* Mount to any point of local FS
* Add repository to TortoiseHG Workbench, using "translated" local path to repository
* Use repository as any other really local

But clone|push way is more natural and bullet-proof (no chances to get corrupted repo, real backup of your local repository on remote host)